# Can I connect objects with javascript?

Tags: raphael, jsplumb, paperjs

I want to make an interface that looks like this

[image]

So here is what the user can do

1- Connect people to each other
2- See some information about each person (the balloon)
3- Move these objects around without them loosing their connections

Then I want to save these connection information using ajax, so that I can see who is connected to who, I also need to redraw these diagrams next time the user sees the page.

It seems like jsPlumb, paperjs, and raphael can all do this and a lot more, my question is which one is suitable for this need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inspect graphiti which is based on raphael.

http://www.draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example

Greetings

Andreas